# WIndows phone 8: Get current audio

Tags: windows-phone-8, background-audio

I want to get current playing audio info(artist, track name) on Windows Phone 8.
On Windows Phone 7 it was possible through XNA functionality using:

```
                var curSong = MediaPlayer.Queue.ActiveSong;
```

But on Windows Phone 8 this method not work, audio which started from another application cannot be detected. 
WP8 provide [BackgroundAudioPlayer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.backgroundaudio.backgroundaudioplayer%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) class with Track property. But when audio playing started from another app Track property value is always null. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try to add the reference to xna manually? You will need to browse to the assembly to add it.

Comment: Thanks for yout answer, Shawn. What did you mean as "add the reference to xna manually"? Assembly Microsoft.XNA.Framework added to project references, but  MediaPlayer.Queue.ActiveSong property is always null on Windows Phone 8 devices.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling FrameworkDispatcher.Update().